# Access to POST vars in php with string name

Tags: php, http-post

Hi, I have a problem when try access to $_POST vars in php. I have a combo with this name "c012". Well, I send the form with this var, and I have checked this var is send ok, and when I try access with this code, where $var1, $var2 and $var3 are numbers:

`$var1 = 0;`
`$var2 = 1;`
`$var3 = 2;`

`$pointer_combo = "c".$var1.$var2.$var3;`
`echo $_POST['$pointer_combo'];`

Don't show anything, but if I try this:

`echo $_POST['c012'];`

Works, and show the value. Whats the problem with code above?

Comment: Don't single-quote `$pointer_combo` in `$_POST['$pointer_combo']` as the variable is not expanded. Vars are expanded in double-quoted strings, but you have no need for quotes at all in that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a dynamic index (index value stored in a variable), you don't need the quotes.

Try this:

```
echo $_POST[$pointer_combo];
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP won't do variable substitution if the value is in single quotes. Only double quotes or no quotes. So

```
echo $_POST[$pointer_combo];
```

Would work, as would:

```
echo $_POST["$pointer_combo"];
```

(But obviously in that second example there isn't much point in the quotes being there!)

Answer (score 1):

Lose the quotes:

```
$_POST[$pointer_combo];
```